# php json upload not being read into variable

Tags: php, json

I am integrating an ERP with a web store, and my custom page for inserting customers is not working.
The live page uses:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

To debug in Eclipse I have substituted the JSON upload text:

```
$data = '[{"ARDivisionNo":"02","CustomerNo":"AMERCON","ContactCode":"MIKE THOMP","CustomerName":"American Concrete Service","fname":"Mike ","lname":"Thompson","EmailAddress":"nobody@gmail.com","Billing_Address1":"11733 Cardinal Circle","Billing_Address2":"","Billing_Address3":"","Billing_City":"Anaheim","Billing_State":"CA","Billing_Zip":"92625","UDF_FC_ENABLED":"Y","UDF_FC_CUSTOMERID":null,"UDF_FC_ADDRESS_BOOK_ID":null,"TelephoneNo1":"5557933264","FaxNo":"","UDF_FC_PW":"pass","UDF_FC_CUSTOMERTYPE":"SUPER"}]';
```

However the debugger skips over this line and $data still shows as uninitialized.

What have I done wrong?

Comment: If the debugger is skipping it is because the code doesn't match.  It probably is trying to find the correct line.  Also note `php://input` is not available for a form with `multipart/form-data` encoding

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond - Could you explain "code doesn't match"?

Comment: When you debug the ide tries to compare the process running with code on your machine and it did not find a match because there is different code on your local machine, this is usually the case with debugging remote applications with modified local code.  Why use php://input when you can just pass the value as a parameter in post and have it appear in $_POST?

Comment: Got the code matching, and processing the text in the php file works in the debugger, but the web site php://input still doesn't work.  I have several other php files in the same project where that same line does work (and this one did too, for a while.)

Comment: What are you trying to upload.  It may make a difference and be affected by the encoding of the post request

Comment: It is JSON, and when I output it to a text file and paste into the php to debug it works.